# Visual Studio 2017 How to add missing dll to C++ project?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a Visual Studio 2017 C++ project which depends on ffmpeg libraries. As of now it crashes at run time because of the missing dependency avformat-58.dll. I've tried adding this file into the project by dragging it into my project but that does not suffice. I tried looking at the Add Reference screen but it is empty. What can I do?

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

On the advice of @HansPassant I added the dll(s) to the project as existing external files. I think there should now be an option somewhere to "Copy to output directory" but I'm not seeing it. Here is what I see when I open property pages of one of the dlls.

[image: file property pages]

@sellotape Here is a screenshot of the window when I just single click.

[image]

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks that sounds promising. I did that and the dll now appears in my Source Files folder. But what is the Copy to Output Directory property?

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry I'm not sure I'm doing it right. Would you look at my updated question? I included a screenshot of what I'm seeing.

Comment: Oh, it is a C project, it makes it harder.  Project > Properties > Build events > Post-build event.  Use xcopy with /d to copy the DLLs to $(TargetDir)

Comment: Wrong properties location, you want the ones you get when you right click the file itself, in the solution explorer.

Comment: @sellotape That's the one I clicked. And in the top left corner you can see it says the file "avcodec-58.dll" which is the one I want to edit.

Comment: Just single-click the file, and the setting to Copy to Output will be in that properties window you can already see below the solution explorer.

Comment: @HansPassant ffmpeg is a C library, but I'm pretty sure my project should be a C++ project since I have main.cpp and it's compiling fine. I included the ffmpeg headers inside an extern "C" block.

Comment: If that project references that DLL, though, it should automatically copy it to the output folder already, without needing to do anything specific to copy it like that.

Comment: @sellotape I updated the question with another screenshot. I just can't seem to find this property.

Comment: Hmm, probably because it's a link to a file outside the solution path. Usually you would copy the needed files into your project location and add them to your project from there, so e.g. build servers, other devs machines, can use them too. NuGet would be better, so this assumes that's not an option here.

Comment: Actually sorry, I've also just realized like Hans did that this isn't a C# project. My comments might well not apply.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I will edit my question to clarify it.

Comment: @HansPassant I'll try the post build event. Is there a way I can use my local reference to the dll inside the xcopy command (as opposed to the absolute path to the dll on my hard drive.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order I can copy the necessary dlls to any directory in the PATH environment variable. There were many dlls already in C:/Windows/System32 already so I just put the ffmpeg dlls there as well and the executable runs.